# « Le vivre ensemble » relève plus du vœu pieux ou de l’injonction que du constat ?

Tags: sens

Ma lecture de [la substantivation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivation) me motive à lire [la suite](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-vivre-ensemble) :

> Le français ne peut pas, contrairement au latin ou au grec, substantiver tous ses infinitifs. On dit *le coucher,* mais non *le dormir*. Si certains verbes substantivés peuvent parfois avoir un complément à l’infinitif (*le savoir-faire, le savoir-vivre*), on évitera d’avoir recours, comme [une mode actuelle] tend à le faire [...], à la substantivation de groupes formés d’un infinitif et d’un adverbe[.]
>
> On entend par exemple parler du *bien mourir*, mais le plus fréquent est *le vivre ensemble*, qui **semble relever plus du vœu pieux ou de l’injonction que du constat**. Faut-il vraiment faire de ce groupe verbal une locution nominale pour redonner un peu d’harmonie à la vie en société ?

En quoi le substantif déploré (c-à-d [le syntagme nominal, la locution nominale](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/noun%20phrase)) *le vivre ensemble* semble-t-il relever plus du vœu pieux ou de l’injonction que du constat ?

Comment: Quel est l'auteur ?

Comment: @cl-r http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-vivre-ensemble ne l'indique pas.

Comment: Quai Conti, lieu des ego éternels ; ne semblent-ils pas considérer que tout ce qui se passe au-delà des limites germanopratines, hors des livres et des journaux n'existe pas ?

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'une expression souvent reprise par les politiques (et du coup les journalistes) pour désigner et appeler à une [cohésion sociale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coh%C3%A9sion_sociale), avec le respect de l'autre, le multiculturalisme, l'Europe...

> - le gouvernement, en voulant imposer la mixité sociale, se livre-t-il à un apartheid inversé ? Ces politiques du **vivre ensemble** imposé sont-elles efficaces ? ([atlantico.fr](http://www.atlantico.fr/decryptage/imposer-gens-qui-ne-veulent-pas-vivre-ensemble-quand-politique-peuplement-socialiste-se-transforme-en-apartheid-inverse-laurent-1992439.html))
> - Un déménagement, c'est encore plus violent qu'un vote. Cela signifie que les gens ne veulent pas d'un "**vivre ensemble**" qu'on leur impose, ce qui n'interdit pas rencontre et fraternité. ([nouvel observateur](http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/politique/20140505.OBS6135/pourquoi-le-vivre-ensemble-c-est-fini.html))
> - Mais le chef de l'État, qui terminait dimanche une tournée très politique aux Antilles, aux allures de campagne électorale, en a profité aussi pour délivrer un plaidoyer pour le **vivre-ensemble** et la République, au lendemain des événements de janvier et en pleine montée en puissance du FN. ([Le Figaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/politique/2015/05/10/01002-20150510ARTFIG00160-en-guadeloupe-francois-hollande-exalte-le-vivre-ensemble.php))

Il ne s'agit pas d'une remarque issue du sens des mots mais d'un état de fait, cette expression n'est utilisée que pour appeler à se respecter ou pour expliquer une philosophie de vie, une ouverture aux autres.

L'auteur critique aussi ces politiques pour leurs emplois de termes phares qu'ils peuvent ensuite marteler afin de faire croire qu'ils agissent quand ils ne font que parler. Ces emplois qui ne se soucient peu ou pas du tout de la grammaire :

> Faut-il vraiment faire de ce groupe verbal une locution nominale pour redonner un peu d’harmonie à la vie en société ?

Comment: La réponse de cl-r est tout à fait juste, mais il me semble qu'une explication plus en détails et quelques exemples étaient intéressants.

Answer (score 2):

En dehors du domaine grammatical, l’auteur sous entend que *le vivre ensemble* n’existe pas dans la réalité, il sort du domaine académique pour introduire une réflexion personnelle sur l’art de vivre.

Ceux qui  parlent  *du vivre ensemble*  le souhaitent ou exhortent les gens à le pratiquer, mais lui ne l'a pas constaté.