# Le « vivre-ensemble/vivre ensemble » en substantif : qui, depuis quand, nuances ?

Tags: infinitif, néologismes, substantivation

J'ai entendu un certain nombre de fois la substantivation de « vivre ensemble », le [*vivre-ensemble*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=21798794), nom masculin (ou sans le trait d'union [*vivre ensemble*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vivre_ensemble)). Le *GDT* le classe dans le domaine de la sociologie :

> Forme de cohésion et de solidarité sociales, de tolérance et de
>   civilité reposant sur des liens qui se déploient sur le plan du vécu
>   et du quotidien entre les individus des différents groupes ou
>   catégories de personnes (âge, sexe, ethnie, etc.) d'une société.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique, *GDT*, vivre-ensemble, 2009 ]

C'est sans doute [plutôt](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le%20vivre%20ensemble%2Cle%20vivre-ensemble&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20vivre%20ensemble%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20vivre%20-%20ensemble%3B%2Cc0) nouveau et c'est absent comme tel du *Larousse* en ligne, *TLFi*, et du *DHLF/Rey* ; l'*Académie française* semble [s'opposer](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-vivre-ensemble) au procédé requis à sa formation et ailleurs on se [questionnait](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14406) sur son propos. Généralement le *TLFi* note l'emploi de [*ensemble*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ensemble/2) comme adverbe pour déterminer un verbe ou un syntagme verbal ; le *DHLF* indique qu'en français contemporain au 20<sup>e</sup>, on a des emplois de *vivre* subissant l'influence de la phénoménologie et de l'existentialisme. On s'y connaît peu.

---

- Depuis quand utilise-t-on cette locution nominale et chez qui en
  particulier d'abord ? S'agit-il vraiment d'un substantif, ou d'une locution où l'on retrouve l'ellipse d'un (groupe de) mot(s) et, le cas échéant, duquel ?
- La portée du sens de la locution au 21<sup>e</sup> est-elle la même
  que celle de la définition présentée plus haut, en sociologie ; en d'autres termes existe-t-il un sens courant qui diffère de celui en sociologie et si oui quel est-il ? A-t-on d'autres précisions ?

Comment: Au sens courant, le <<vivre ensemble>> n'a qu'une définition et c'est celle que tu as donnée. Je définirais cela comme un mode de vie, un synonyme de tolérance et savoir vivre.

Comment: A mon sens, il s'agit d'une locution où l'on a fait une ellipse: _le fait de vivre ensemble_ serait ainsi l'origine. (Pas de source à citer, désolé)

Comment: @Rémi L'art de ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La plus ancienne citation que je trouve sur [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le%20vivre%20ensemble%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1964&lr=lang_fr) est une [traduction de Cicéron par M. Nisard](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oCAKxquTgAwC&pg=PA620&dq=%22le+vivre+ensemble%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22le%20vivre%20ensemble%22&f=false), dans laquelle « le *vivre ensemble* » est en italiques et rapproché du mot latin *convivium*. La formulation montre que l'expression n'est pas considérée comme habituelle en français.

[Plus tard](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le+vivre+ensemble%22&lr=lang_fr&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1965%2Ccd_max%3A1980&tbm=bks) le terme apparaît surtout chez des sociologues.

Je me demande si la formulation ne s'est pas répandue par calque de l'allemand, plutôt que du latin. En allemand, ce genre de formation où un verbe devient un nom et où l'on peut facilement lui ajouter un adverbe est assez courante. On la retrouve facilement en philosophie¹. En allemand, [*Zusammenleben*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zusammenleben) est un terme de sociologie [bien établi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Zusammenleben&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CZusammenleben%3B%2Cc0).

Je ne connais pas à ce terme d'autre sens, et Nisard et les sociologues l'utilisent dans le même sens bien qu'ils ne se soient probablement pas influencés mutuellement. Quoi qu'en dise l'Académie française, nominaliser un verbe est possible en français, même si c'est bien moins systématique qu'en allemand.

Je pense que changer « vivre ensemble » en « l'art de vivre ensemble » est un contresens. Le « vivre ensemble », cela couvre tous les besoins de la vie en commun : le « vivre ensemble » couvre le problème, alors que « l'art de vivre ensemble » ne couvre que ses solutions.

On pourrait rallonger en « le fait de vivre ensemble », mais là aussi il y aurait un contresens, parce que cette formulation est plus générique. « Le vivre ensemble » désigne les problèmes de la vie en société, alors que « le fait de vivre ensemble » désignerait plutôt les problèmes de cohabitation d'un groupe de personnes données, par exemple un couple ou des voisins.

¹  <sub>Par exemple le célèbre [Dasein](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein), littéralement *sein* (« être ») + *da* (« là ») → *das Dasein* (« l'être-là »), et dans la langue courante *présence*, *existence*, mais pas vraiment traduisible chez Heidegger.</sub>

Comment: Your mention of “existence” in the footnote & link to Heidegger reminded me of the similar geo-political notion of “[Peaceful] **Co**existence” used often during the Cold War. (Re possibility of an ellipse: If adding “L’art de” goes too far to solutions and “Le fait de” too far to particular cases, maybe “Le sens/sentiment de” could be considered as a more neutral and general candidate, as “The sense/feeling of togetherness” in English leaves open the possibility that the sense/feeling is perhaps unjustified &/or unfounded) cc: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ +1